# Pointing multiple domains to specific pages via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Let's say may main domain is www.mysite.com and that I'm using the following rewrite in my hataccess

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

All good so far! However, I also need other domains to redirect to specific pages on the site. For example, if somebody types www.mysite.nl they will be redirected to www.mysite.com/neatherlands. The issue is when I pop the below into my htaccess file I get a server error. I think this is because of the final rewrite. It's a pretty mad set-up

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.nl$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/netherlands/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.be$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/belgium/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.co.\uk$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions about what to do?

Comment: Apart from an escaping error (`.\uk` instead of `\.uk`) I don't see anything obvious that is wrong. It should not create an internal server error though. In the worst case scenario you get the too many redirects browser error. Could you enable logging (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging), restart your Apache, and redo the request, then check your apache error log?

Comment: Good spot, Sumurai8. I think there is a couple of of unconnected things going on here that have confused me. First, although you say it shouldn't have caused an error, when I corrected my typo the error message no longer appears. Second, I'm pretty sure that the DNS has not been set up correctly for the .co.uk, be and nl domains. Cheers!